# dart xml with external files

Tags: xml, dart

I've been able to follow all the examples of dart-xml but that is only for a dart file containing xml in a variable. How to i parse and create external xml files?

If I try and import an xml file directly dart usually gets stuck on the first character of the xml file '<'.

How would I write the given example from dart-xml https://github.com/renggli/dart-xml? I can print it to the shell using

```
print(bookshelfXml.toString());
```

but how to i save || pipe it to an external file? I've tried to use dart:io a little but not having any success at the moment.

Comment: Is this for code running in the browser or on the server?

Comment: Hi Zochi, At the moment i'm just working on dart:io to be able to serve xml files. However, I'd like to have xml and xslt files available to polymer elements eventually.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks renggli @ github, zoeichi for dart:io assistance.

To do the examples from the [dart-xml](https://github.com/renggli/dart-xml) repo with external files try;

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:xml/xml.dart' as xml;

void main (){

//create file bookshelf.xml seperately using example on github.
// <?xml version="1.0"?>
//     <bookshelf>
//       <book>
//         <title lang="english">Growing a Language</title>
//         <price>29.99</price>
//       </book>
//       <book>
//         <title lang="english">Learning XML</title>
//         <price>39.95</price>
//       </book>
//       <price>132.00</price>
//     </bookshelf>

//parse external file
var book = xml.parse(new File('bookshelf.xml').readAsStringSync());
print(book.toString());
print('---');

//finding elements
var titles = book.findAllElements('title');
titles
    .map((node) => node.text)
    .forEach(print);

//finding elements, convert strings to compute sum
var total =  book.findAllElements('book')
    .map((node) => double.parse(node.findElements('price').single.text))
    .reduce((a, b) => a + b);
print(total);   
print('---');

//build external file using example
var builder = new xml.XmlBuilder();
builder.processing('xml', 'version="1.0"');
builder.element('bookshelf', nest: () {
  builder.element('book', nest: () {
    builder.element('title', nest: () {
      builder.attribute('lang', 'english');
      builder.text('Growing a Language');
    });
    builder.element('price', nest: 29.99);
  });
  builder.element('book', nest: () {
    builder.element('title', nest: () {
      builder.attribute('lang', 'english');
      builder.text('Learning XML');
    });
    builder.element('price', nest: 39.95);
  });
  builder.element('price', nest: 132.00);
});
var bookshelfXml = builder.build();

//create and write eternal file name and contents 
var buildXml = new File('bookshelfDartCreated.xml');
buildXml.writeAsString(bookshelfXml.toString());

//check newly created file
new File('bookshelfDartCreated.xml').readAsString().then((String contents) {
  print(contents);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
import 'dart:io';

...

var file = new File('path/to/file.xml');
file.writeAsString(bookshelfXml.toString());
```

See also:

- https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.18.1/dart-io/File-class.html
- https://www.dartlang.org/dart-vm/dart-by-example
- https://www.dartlang.org/articles/dart-vm/io

Comment: thanks. that works fine. I just changed the small typo error '  var file = new File('pathToFile.xml');
file.writeAsString(bookshelfXml.toString());'

Comment: How to I parse an external document? If I read it in as a string the 'xml.parse(importedFile.xml);' only returns errors.

Comment: If i use the provided example on dart-xml git page then it ends with 'var document = xml.parse(bookshelfXml);' but how could I do that with an external file instead of having the xml in the dart file itself?

Comment: Thanks a bunch, Gunther. I'm glad i asked. (p.s. added the closing quote to the code you provided; 'xml.parse(new File('myfile.xml').readAsStringSync());'

Comment: I see. Sorry for the mistake. If that answers your question it would be great if you could accept the answer to make it obvious your problem is solved by clicking the white checkmark below the up/downvote-buttons.

Comment: thanks for your help, zoeichi. i like xml and look forward to future discussions.

Comment: Sure, keep the questions coming :)